# one 2 many jpa qry with join

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to use jpa with join to qry one to many entities

Entity Table Unit (one)
Entity Table Appartment (many)

I am using the following JPA

```
@Query("Select u from Unit u inner join u.appartmentList a " +
        "where u.unitNumber IN :unitNumbers " +
        "and a.appNumber= :appNumber")
Page findApt(@Param("unitNumbers") Collection<String> unitNumbers,
               @Param("appNumber") Integer appNumber,
               Pageable pageable);enter code here
```

I need to be able to get 2 appartments (one in each unit passed as unita,unitb).
if I do a GET for ../findStuff?unitNumbers=unita,unitb&appNumber=1

But I get all appartments in each unit instead, not just appNumber=1 in each unit.

Any idea on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: So does a unit contain multiple apartments?  It looks like you are selecting units when you want to be selecting apartments.  or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query on `Appartment`.

```
@Query("select a from Appartment a where" + 
" a.appNumber= :appNumber and a.unit.unitNumber IN :unitNumbers"
```

If `unit` is lazy fetched, you may want to fetch it with the first query, so the query becomes:

```
@Query("select a from Appartment a join fetch a.unit where" + 
    " a.appNumber= :appNumber and a.unit.unitNumber IN :unitNumbers"
```

Comment: Thank you.   I need to get back a unit(s) attributes plus the apartment for that unit.

Comment: You have the `unit` in the `apartment` -> `apartment.getUnit()`. If `unit` is lazy fetched you may add `join fetch a.unit` in the query.

Comment: Thank you so much.  In the jpa repo interface,  public interface ApartmentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ApartmentDataDto, String> {} how do you make the repo aware of the Unit entity?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't see your code but It looks like your entity for Apartment is `ApartmentDataDto`, this class must have the `Unit unit` attribute, assuming you've set the one-to-many relationship properly. The interface does not need to be aware of it, it's enough for the entity to reference it.

Comment: Hello, After hours of trying ... I still can't get the qry to work with join fetch.   I get this error [[QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list]] for this qrt [[@Query("select p from ApartmentDataDto p join fetch  p.unit e where" +
            " p.size= :size and e.unitNumber IN :unitNumbers")]].  Unit is Lazy Fetched.   I tried select p, e ... same this.   Any thought what this error means?   'he fetched association was not present in the select lis' seems obvious, but adding select p, e not helping.

Comment: Glad to hear :)